# Can't show variables inside Django blocks

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a simple parent template like this that uses Django blocks

```
//base.html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

{% block content%}

{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

But whenever I try to print the variables passed by views.py inside the block nothing is neither displayed nor received, when I put all the html code together in a single file without a parent template it works perfect.

This is the basic idea of the block

```
//block.html
{% extends 'folder/base.html'%}
  {% block content  %}

     <h1> {{data}} </h1>

  {% endblock %}
```

And this is the content of the views.py function:

```
def function(request):
    return render(request,'folder/block.html',{'data':'someRandomString'})
```

Comment: Please try to inspect "page source" in the browser and validate your html markup. For instance, your parent template is missing opening `<html>` tag.

Comment: Show us your app architecture in order to view your templates path

Comment: @IvanStarostin  Sorry, I did not include the complete code, now it is correct, the HTML code of the block is working perfectly but the variables are still not received

Comment: For debugging purpose put some text inside `block content` of parent template - does it appear on the page? Or does `<h1>` from the child template appear on the page instead (still without variable value)?

Comment: @Wariored it is fixed now, thanks,  it seems like the problem was a call to the wrong template or rute , btw, I'm relatively new here, so...what should I do with the question? Should I delete it?